# sql / mysql problems logging in :o(

Tags: mysql, sql

I seem to have destroyed SQL, or locked myself out please help!

`$ mysql`

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

`$ mysql -u root`

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)

`$ mysql -u root -p`
`Enter password:` (entered root password)

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

`$ mysqld --skip-grant-tables`

> 2020-02-01T14:11:49.594102Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server]
>   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as
>   process 1045
>
> 2020-02-01T14:11:49.611453Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting
>   lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/
>   is case insensitive
>
> 2020-02-01T14:11:49.700657Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to
>   lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.229153Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to
>   lock ./ibdata1 error: 35
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.234177Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating
>   system error number 35 in a file operation.
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.235324Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error
>   number 35 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.237651Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012215] [InnoDB] Cannot open
>   datafile './ibdata1'
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.239868Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012959] [InnoDB] Could not
>   open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data
>   files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now
>   edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove
>   the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB
>   only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any
>   way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your
>   precious data!
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.241047Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin
>   initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file.
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.244025Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to
>   initialize DD Storage Engine
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.246381Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data
>   Dictionary initialization failed.
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.248513Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
>
> 2020-02-01T14:13:30.258156Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server]
>   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld
>   8.0.19)  Homebrew.

Please help! Noob here, trying to learn!

Comment: Did you have some data in MySQL. If not try to reinstalling MySQL. Else try to run MySQL as root.

Comment: check the filesystem, you are missing some files and i hope you have a backup at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it with a reinstallation, thanks.